# How to run GUI test via squish without X server

Tags: squish

i also have same doubt... how to run a test cases to test AUT in background so that i can work on the some other task on my machine. While testing in squish is running so many pops ups and AUT features keep on coming to ur screen and its annoying while you are working on something else .

Answer (score 5):

As I understand a key moment of question is work in parallel with tests , when they emulate keyboard and mouse events. So "without X server" I understand as "without affect to real user actions".

For this goal I used Xvfb on Linux and sysinternals desktops ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx) on Windows when I created squish GUI tests. And I can work in parallel with tests running.

I saved such a script to `/etc/init.d/xvfb`

```
#! /bin/sh    

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Xvfb
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:
# X-Start-Before:
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Virtual Frame Buffer
### END INIT INFO

XVFB=/usr/bin/Xvfb
XVFBARGS=":1 -screen 5 2560x1440x24 -ac"
PIDFILE=/var/run/xvfb.pid
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting Xvfb"
    start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --background --exec $XVFB -- $XVFBARGS
    echo "."
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping Xvfb"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE
    echo "."
    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 2
    $0 start
    ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/xvfb {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

And now I can do `/etc/init.d/xvfb start` or `/etc/init.d/xvfb stop`. Also, to start Xvfb automaticaly at boot time you can use: `update-rc.d xvfb defaults 92`

After this, before start GUI tests I use `export DISPLAY=":1.5"` in  terminal console from which i start tests. Then tests run without visible GUI touching, and I can work in parallel.

As for "desktops" (for Windows) - it creates additional 4 desktops in Windows, you can start tests in one of desktops and switch to another one to work.

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted.  Upvoting since it seems like a good idea to me.  What utility in the sysinternals suite are you using for virtual display?  Any experience with custom openGL running in your app on the virtual windows display?  Thanks

Comment: I also have no idea about downvoting, probably I have some hater, there are some of my posts downvoted and never I had explanation.  :) I did not use virtual display on Windows. I used separated desktops using 'desktops' utility:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx. So I worked in one desktop and ran tests in parallel on another desktop. I have no experience about openGL in some virtual displays, but I believe there will not be any problems with this utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can run some exixsting test scripts trough SquishServer and in the same time, also have the SquishIDE opened to write some more tests. 
Is this basically what you're asking?

I have installed squish-5.1.1-qt48x-win32-msvc9.
I also use some virtual machines to run the tests. 
While the tests run on those virtual machines (that run on my local computer, but it could be a server) I have the SquishIDE opened and develop some more tests.

A starting point for obtaining this configuration should be the files from here:

```
C:\squish-5.1.1-qt48x-win32-msvc9\squish-5.1.1-qt48x-win32-msvc9\examples\regressiontesting\
```

Take a look at them because I used those.
Indeed, I have some modifications in them, and you need some python knowledge. If you don't know this language that well, you should call someone who knows it.

With those files, you can specify which tests to run, configure the squish_server and also, after tests run you will obtain some reports in form of [*.html] file.

Hope this helps. Also some additional help you can find here: http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/
at **chapter 17. User Guide**